# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON' - Trying to add sub data to an existing row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I need your help, I think what I am trying to do looks right, but the server is kicking back an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'". Basically, I am trying to add sub row data (LastName and FirstName) ie. John Smith to an office assignment by floor and office #, thereby indicating in my excel table that there are 2 employees assigned to that office (as per the excel example below).

Maybe I am going about this all wrong but a fresh set of eyes wouldn't hurt.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_accdb 
(
     Floor INT,
     Office VARCHAR(255),
     Location VARCHAR(255),
     LastName VARCHAR(255),
     FirstName VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_accdb (Floor, Office, Location, LastName, FirstName) 
VALUES ('2', 'B-47A', 'NCR-Tower C', 'Doe', 'Jane')

INSERT INTO tbl_accdb (LastName, Firstname) 
VALUES ('Smith', 'John')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Office='B-47A', Floor='2'
```

[image]

Comment: `insert ... on duplicate key update` is MySQL syntax, it is not supported in SQL Server.

Comment: There is no such thing as *sub row data* in SQL. You can insert a full row, containing all the columns of the table.

Comment: Even if that syntax were valid in SQL Server, you have defined no primary key, no unique constraint, no unique index which is required to know if there is a "duplicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike spreadsheet software, relational databases are based on strongly typed rectangular structures called tables where all rows need to have the same exact columns (same number and same data types) and rows do not have any specific order (result sets can be sorted, tables cannot).

In this case you'd need to have two different tables (one for locations, one for employees). The locations table should have a unique identifier (primary key) that you'd use in the employees table (foreign key):

```
location_id | floor | office | location
------------+-------+--------+------------
          1 |     2 | B-47A  | NRC-Tower C
```

```
employee_id | location_id | last_name | first_name
------------+-------------+-----------+-----------
          1 |           1 | Doe       | Jane
          2 |           1 | Smith     | John
```